# Complicated referencing with dictionaries, python

Tags: python, dictionary, lookup

Suppose i have two dictionaries as follows:

```
vertices_on_tetrahedron = {
    0: [0, 1, 3, 7],
    1: [0, 1, 5, 7],
    2: [0, 4, 5, 7],
    3: [0, 2, 3, 7],
    4: [0, 4, 6, 7],
    5: [0, 2, 6, 7],
}
data_on_tetrahedron = {
    0: [78, 79, 80],
    1: [111, 112, 113],
    2: [144, 145, 146],
    3: [45, 46, 47],
    4: [177, 178, 179],
    5: [201, 202, 203],
}
```

Next, what I am trying to do is to make a dictionary like this:

```
result = {
    0: [78, 79, 80, 111, 112, 113, 144, 145, 146, 45, 46, 47, 177, 178, 179, 201, 202, 203],
    1: [78, 79, 80, 111, 112, 113],
    2: [45, 46, 47, 201, 202, 203],
    3: [78, 79, 80, 45, 46, 47],
    4: [144, 145, 146, 177, 178, 179],
    5: [111, 112, 113, 144, 145, 146],
    6: [177, 178, 179, 201, 202, 203],
    7: [78, 79, 80, 111, 112, 113, 144, 145, 146, 45, 46, 47, 177, 178, 179, 201, 202, 203],
}
```

This dictionary can be obtained as follows (there must be other ways). First I need to rearrange dict `vertices_on_tetrahedron` to some temporary one:

```
tets_sharing_vertex = {
    0: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    1: [0, 1],
    2: [3, 5],
    3: [0, 3],
    4: [2, 4],
    5: [1, 2],
    6: [4, 5],
    7: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
```

This is a dictionary, in which each key represent one number from the value list of dictionary `vertices_on_tetrahedron`, and value is the list of keys of dictionary `vertices_on_tetrahedron` which have this number.

Then, the final result is a dictionary with keys equal to keys of dictionary `tets_sharing_vertex` and the values taken from dictionary `b` according to the value list from dictionary `tets_sharing_vertex`.

I have it implemented as follows (which is very ugly, I admit):

```
def find_tets_sharing_vertex(vertex,input_dict):
    tmp = []
    for k, v in input_dict.iteritems():
        if vertex in v:
            tmp.append(k)

    return tmp

result_lst = []
for vertex in vertices:
    tmp = find_tets_sharing_vertex(vertex, vertices_on_tetrahedron)
    result_lst.append([b[i] for i in tmp])

result_tmp = dict(zip(values,result_lst))
result = {}
for i in range(len(result_tmp)):
    result[i] = flatten(result_tmp[i])
```

Here, `vertices` is the list of all possible entries of values of dictionary `vertices_on_tetrahedron`. Function `flatten()` flattens the list of lists: `[[0], [1]] -> [0, 1]`.

Conceptually, `result_lst` solves the problem, however it looks like this:

```
[[[78, 79, 80], [111, 112, 113], [144, 145, 146], [45, 46, 47], [177, 178, 179], [201, 202, 203]], ... ]
```

That is why I am doing one more step with `result_tmp` and `result`.

This implementation works, but slowly, and I actually need it to work on large dictionaries `vertices_on_tetrahedron` and `data_on_tetrahedron`. The structure of `vertices_on_tetrahedron` is always the same: each key has the value list of no more than 4 items. But there may be thousands of keys. Same for `vertices_on_tetrahedron`, each value is a list of no more than 3 items.

Unfortunately I am getting `vertices_on_tetrahedron` and `data_on_tetrahedron` in this form, so I cannot reconsider changing data structures to avoid this.

If someone could also recommend some references to read on this sort of problems, I would much appreciate it.

Comment: What does `a` do? It seems that `result` can be constructed only from `b` and `c`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I don't have `c`. I start with `a`, `b` and `values`.

Comment: Your code would be easier to read if you used meaningful names. What is `myfunction` supposed to do? Why are there three results (`result_lst`, `result_tmp`, `result`) and what's the relation between them? And so on... Please spare me a headache :)

Comment: @Pukki What is `values`? I think `c` can be constructed directly from `a`.

Comment: @yangjie After I edited the question, it is `vertices`. And it is just the list of all labels of vertices i have. In this example it is `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, construct `tets_sharing_vertex` from `vertices_on_tetrahedron`

```
from pprint import pprint
from collections import defaultdict

tets_sharing_vertex = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in vertices_on_tetrahedron.items():
    for x in v:
        tets_sharing_vertex[x].append(k)

pprint(tets_sharing_vertex)
```

Out:

```
{0: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 1: [0, 1],
 2: [3, 5],
 3: [0, 3],
 4: [2, 4],
 5: [1, 2],
 6: [4, 5],
 7: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

Second, get `result` from `data_on_tetrahedron` and `tets_sharing_vertex`

```
from itertools import chain

result = {k: list(chain.from_iterable(data_on_tetrahedron[x] for x in v)) for k, v in tets_sharing_vertex.items()}

pprint(result, width=100)
```

Out:

```
{0: [78, 79, 80, 111, 112, 113, 144, 145, 146, 45, 46, 47, 177, 178, 179, 201, 202, 203],
 1: [78, 79, 80, 111, 112, 113],
 2: [45, 46, 47, 201, 202, 203],
 3: [78, 79, 80, 45, 46, 47],
 4: [144, 145, 146, 177, 178, 179],
 5: [111, 112, 113, 144, 145, 146],
 6: [177, 178, 179, 201, 202, 203],
 7: [78, 79, 80, 111, 112, 113, 144, 145, 146, 45, 46, 47, 177, 178, 179, 201, 202, 203]}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work much faster than your current solution:

```
import collections

result = collections.defaultdict(list)
[result[v2].extend(data_on_tetrahedron[k1]) for k1,v1 in vertices_on_tetrahedron.items() for v2 in v1]

print result
```

Giving:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {0: [78, 79, 80, 111, 112, 113, 144, 145, 146, 45, 46, 47, 177, 178, 179, 201, 202, 203], 1: [78, 79, 80, 111, 112, 113], 2: [45, 46, 47, 201, 202, 203], 3: [78, 79, 80, 45, 46, 47], 4: [144, 145, 146, 177, 178, 179], 5: [111, 112, 113, 144, 145, 146], 6: [177, 178, 179, 201, 202, 203], 7: [78, 79, 80, 111, 112, 113, 144, 145, 146, 45, 46, 47, 177, 178, 179, 201, 202, 203]})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
result =dict((i, []) for i in range(8))
for l in vertices_on_tetrahedron.keys():
    for j in vertices_on_tetrahedron[l]:
            result[j].extend(data_on_tetrahedron[l])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
result = {}
for k,v in vorticies_on_tetrahedron:
    result[k] = [data_on_tetrahedron[i] for i in v]
```

And if you are going to use this multiple times you could wrap it in a function.